# Prove $ \frac{x-1}{y-1} + \frac{y-1}{z-1} + \frac{z-1}{x-1} \ge \frac{x+1}{y+1} + \frac{y+1}{z+1} + \frac{z+1}{x+1}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, symmetry

Prove that for real numbers $x,y,z>1$,

$$   \frac{x-1}{y-1}  + \frac{y-1}{z-1} + \frac{z-1}{x-1} \ge \frac{x+1}{y+1}  + \frac{y+1}{z+1} + \frac{z+1}{x+1}$$

---

It is tempting to use AM-GM for LHS and RHS:

$$  \frac{x-1}{y-1}  + \frac{y-1}{z-1} + \frac{z-1}{x-1} \ge 3 $$
$$ \frac{x+1}{y+1}  + \frac{y+1}{z+1} + \frac{z+1}{x+1} \ge 3$$

but I don't see this can be continued.

I am looking for another solution than the solution written below:

---

**Solution 1:**

Notice

$$\frac{x-1}{y-1} - \frac{x+1}{y+1} = \frac{(y+1)(x-1) - (y-1)(x+1)}{y^{2}-1} = 2\frac{(x-y)}{y^{2}-1}$$
so it is non-negative if $x \ge y$. Similarly for the others.

The problem's inequality is equivalent with

$$ \frac{(x-y)}{y^{2}-1} + \frac{(y-z)}{z^{2}-1} + \frac{(z-x)}{x^{2}-1} \ge 0$$

My take is that, WLOG: let $x = \max \{x,y,z\}$, and if $x \ge y \ge z$:

write

$$ \frac{(x-y)}{y^{2}-1} + \frac{(y-z)}{z^{2}-1} + \frac{(z-x)}{x^{2}-1} $$
$$ = \frac{(x-y)}{y^{2}-1} + \frac{(y-z)}{z^{2}-1} + \frac{(z-x+y-y)}{x^{2}-1} $$
$$ = \frac{(x-y)}{y^{2}-1} + \frac{(y-z)}{z^{2}-1} + \frac{-(y-z) -(x-y)}{x^{2}-1} $$
$$ = (x-y) \frac{x^{2}-y^{2}}{(x^{2}-1)(y^{2}-1)} + (y-z) \frac{y^{2}-z^{2}}{(y^{2}-1)(z^{2}-1)} \ge 0$$

and similarly for $x \ge z \ge y$.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2462971/42969

Comment: Or https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1525182p9137180 on AoPS.